# osmnx road connecting two city aren't identified (missing node of border)

Tags: python, graph, networkx, osmnx

I have an Dijsktra Algorithm that I apply on a graph that I get from open street map. It works fine with a single graph.

But when I compose a graph of two neighboring city, the same algorithm doesn't find any way between the graphs .. I noticied that road connecting two city weren't identified by any osmid. :-/

Did I missed some thing ?

```
class Pathfinding(nx.MultiDiGraph):

    def __init__(self, incomin_graphe_data = None, **attr):
        nx.MultiDiGraph.__init__(self,incomin_graphe_data,**attr)

    def dijsktra(self,depart,final):

        inf = float("inf")
        F ,ds, s= set(), None ,None
        D = {i: inf for i in self.nodes}
        D[ depart ] = 0
        pred = {}
        priority_queue = [(0 , depart)]

        while s != final:

            ds, s = heapq.heappop(priority_queue)
            F.add(s)
            for y in self.neighbors(s):    

                w = self[s][y][0]['lenght']
                dy = ds + w

                if y not in F :
                    if D[y] > dy :
                        D[y] = dy
                        heapq.heappush(priority_queue,(dy,y))
                        pred[y] = s

        path = [s]
        while s != depart:
            s = pred[s]
            path.append(s)
        return path
```

There is the Dijkstra that I use and the following type graph are MultiDiGraph.

```
add_Aubervilliers = "Aubervilliers, France" 
Graphe_Aubervilliers = ox.graph_from_place(add_Aubervilliers, network_type='drive')

add_Saint_denis = " Saint denis, France "
Graphe_Saint_denis = ox.graph_from_place(add_Saint_denis, network_type = "drive") 
Graph_Paris_Auber = nx.compose_all([ Graphe_Saint_denis, Graphe_Aubervilliers ])
```

I also tryied with the following commande

```
add_Saint_denis = " Saint denis, France "
Graphe_Saint_denis = ox.graph_from_adress(add_Saint_denis, infrastructure='way['highway']')
```

But it give the same problem... Did I missed something ?

Comment: Could you post the code you are using to find the route with nx?

Comment: It's not a code that I use from nx library. I built it and it works fine for one graph that I'm downloading. The problem, I think, when I merge two graphs they doesn't share the border line of node connection roads..

Comment: Please try the networkx functions `shortest_path` and `has_path` to make sure that there is nothing wrong with your implementation.  https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/shortest_paths.html

Comment: The algorithm works, but I think that fusion of graph block somewhere .. or the importation fails .. :-/

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to set `truncate_by_edge` to True.